# Select2 3.5 how long does cache last

Tags: jquery-select2

Hi i'm using Select2 on Rails application.
ex:

```
searchField.select2({
   cache: true})
```

How many time does cache last?

Answer (score 0):

The length of time that a cache lasts depends on a variety of factors, including the type of cache, the amount of data stored in the cache, and how often the cache is used. Generally, caches can last for days, weeks, or even months.